# PHP "unset()" function works before the previous code

Tags: php, loops, parameter-passing, session-variables

I have a problem.

I passed my data (as session) in the Graph Object in another page, and if I don't unset the session after, I see two identical graphs, else I don't see any graph.
I tried with unset, var=NULL, declaring the session outside the while loop with =array(); but all method failed. I'm getting crazy! Please, light me with your knowledges. Thanks.

This is the code (sorry, but I'm not able to indent your code in this site):

```
//STATISTICHE.PHP

<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/stile.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php

include_once("../../classi/utils.lib.php");
include_once("../../classi/license.lib.php");
include_once("../../classi/funzioni.php");
include_once("../../classi/config.php");
include_once("../../classi/auth.lib.php");

list($status, $user) = auth_get_status();

if($status == AUTH_LOGGED && license_has($user, "sede_centrale"))
{
    menu();
    echo "<h1>STATISTICHE</h1>";

    $query="SELECT nome FROM negozi ORDER BY id ASC";
    $risultato=$db_magazzino->query($query);
    while($negozio=$risultato->fetch_assoc())
    {      
        $rimanenze=rimanenze($negozio['nome'], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        $query2="SELECT * FROM elenco_movimenti WHERE causale='Vendita al dettaglio' AND fornitore='".$negozio['nome']."' ORDER BY data DESC";
        $risultato2=$db_magazzino->query($query2);
        while($scarico=$risultato2->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $_SESSION['data'][$scarico['data']]=$scarico['quantita'];
            //echo $_SESSION['data'][$scarico['data']];
        }
        //var_dump($rimanenze);
        if(count($rimanenze)>0)
        {
            echo "<h2>Grafico delle vendite di ".$negozio['nome'].":</h2>";
            echo "<h4>Valore magazzino ".$negozio['nome'].": ".$rimanenze[count($rimanenze)-1]['valorizzazione_magazzino']." Euro</h3>";
            //var_dump($_SESSION['data']);
            if($_SESSION['data']!=NULL){
                echo "<br/><img src=\"grafico.php\"/>";
                unset($_SESSION['data']);}
            }
            //$risultato2->close();
        }

    } else
       non_autorizzato();
?>
</body>
```

GRAFICO.PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("../../classi/phpgraphlib-master/phpgraphlib.php");
    $graph=new PHPGraphLib(1000,500);
    //Aggiungo i valori di cui sopra
    $graph->addData($_SESSION['data']);
    //Imposto il titolo
    $graph->setTitle("Prodotti venduti");
    //Indichiamo alla libreria di non mostrare le barre
    $graph->setBars(false);
    //Di conseguenza segnaliamo che si tratta di un grafico a linee
    $graph->setLine(true);
    //Visualizza un bollino nel punto del valore indicato
    $graph->setDataPoints(true);
    //Indichiamo il colore del bollino
    $graph->setDataPointColor("yellow");
    //Visualizza il valore del punto
    $graph->setDataValues(true);
    //Indichiamo il colore
    $graph->setDataValueColor("blue");     
    //Creo il grafico
    $graph->createGraph(); 
?>
```

Comment: You're setting SESSION[data] with every while loop cycle.

Comment: can't i set the session, pass the data to the graph.php, and then unset it in the cycle??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) functions instead of just checking if `$_SESSION['data']` is equal to `null`.

These functions can be used to check for the existence of a variable as well as if their value is non-empty.

Comment: You changed `if($_SESSION['data']!=NULL){` to `if (!empty($_SESSION['data'])) {`?  If so, have you tried modifying `unset($_SESSION['data']);` to `$_SESSION['data'] = null;`?

Comment: yes, also outside the if, at the end of the while cycle (before the parenthetis) .don't work :/ the session is set in the page statistiche.php (i tested with var dump). i don't know in the other page because it's an image.

Comment: i'm trying with a header(''). It see the other session variables, but don't see that.

Comment: doesn't work with session destroy before of after the cycle, too.... also if i put it inside the page out of the cycle

Answer (score 0):

You call the grahico.php right before you unset the SESSION variable. Basically it comes down to knowing what is in this SESSION[data]
Perform a debug action. Place the following in your code and paste the result.

```
if ($_SESSION['data'] != NULL) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION['data']);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;

    echo "<br/><img src=\"grafico.php\"/>";
    unset($_SESSION['data']);
}
```